# Rhino.Python and .NET framework

Tags: python, .net, rhino3d

What is [Rhino.Python](https://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinopython/what-is-rhinopython/)? I came across it and also knew that it can use classes from .NET framework. How different is it from the common version of Python?

How mature and stable is this technology?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Rhino.Python](http://python.rhino3d.com/) is

> is a powerful scripting language in Rhino 5.0 & 6.0 for 32 and 64-bit
>   Windows as well as Rhino 5 for Mac.

[Rhino](http://www.it.rhino3d.com/) is world class 3D modelling tool architectured like plugin-based system.

In other words, `RhinoPython` is a kind of DSL(Domain Specific Language) for Rhino. Like (if I'm not mistaken) Lisp was (or still is) for AutoCAD.

I hope this helps.